# Javascript prototype returning value is undefined even though it's correct in the prototype method

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js

I'm trying to create a simple method to convert xml to json. I'm trying to do it using javascript's prototype because i'm trying to learn how to use prototype and because I want to be able to do something like `myXmlString.toJson();`

I have the script below which demonstrates that the xml string gets converted to a json object just fine inside the method, but when i try to call the method it is undefined.

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;  // Used to parse the returned xml (ick) to json (yum)

String.prototype.toJson = function() {
  parseString(this, {explicitArray: false}, function (err, jsonResult) {

    if(err) {
      console.log('err');
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }

    console.log('inside toJSON');
    console.log(jsonResult); // <-- Prints a json object as expected

    return jsonResult;
  });
}

var mystring = '<parent><child>3</child></parent>';
console.log(mystring); // Prints an xml string

mystring.toJson(); // Should this convert the variable mystring to a json structure?
console.log(mystring); // Prints the xml string
console.log(mystring.toJson()); // Prints undefined. Why?
```

Comment: You're going to end up spending weeks of your life writing a proper XML parser, when you should just be using the built in parser instead. Modern browsers have a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), use that to get a DOM, then parse all the elements and their attributes into an object, and use JSON.stringify.

Comment: @adeneo, in all fairness, it doesn't look like he's running this in the browser. Still, I agree with you that a proper parser should be used.

Comment: I'm running this as a node.js script in my backend REST server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your toJson method, you should return the value parseString returns.  At the moment, you just execute parseString without returning the value it returns.

Comment: I have `return jsonResult;`